# Let me temporarily mark a flag as 'safe' from automatic dismissal

Tags: feature-request, flags, moderator-tools

For the nth time this year, I accidentally dismissed an 'other' flag by closing the question. I didn't want to dismiss said 'other' flag.

Sometimes I just want to close a question *without* dismissing the flag on it - in this case, it was a migration flag. I wasn't sure whether we wanted to migrate the question, but I knew it was off topic. I closed it as such... and of course the flag went away. I would have really liked to have that flag stick around until we figured out whether we wanted to migrate it.

Given this, I'd like to float an idea: What if moderators could mark a flag as 'safe' from automatic dismissal temporarily?

I'd like to see a toggle thing of some kind on the flag overlay - I don't think this needs to be in the queue itself:

[image]

Turning this on would:

1. Only apply for a very limited period of time, probably less than 10 minutes. I just want to take an action or two on the question.
2. Keep the flag from being dismissed when I take an action on it - closing, deleting, etc.

Thoughts?

Comment: This seems like an awful lot of overhead. Surely there's a simpler solution? How often are you paralyzed with indecision when it comes to migrations?

Comment: @Shog9 I definitely agree that this would be a lot of overhead, and there's probably a simpler solution. It's fairly rare, and this was just the last one - but I *would* like some way to take action on a flagged post without dismissing the flag.

Comment: I don't think we need the timer for ten minutes or anything. If the flag is still around after we don't expect it to be, it would be simple enough to check back and notice that it's set to be sticky. But I do think there's value in this. I've definitely been in your position for that as well.

Answer (score 3):

I agree. This is up for debate, but I think best-practice should be keeping a flag open until you're completely done handling it, and your feature request would be conducive to that.

I have a feeling this will be unpopular, and it's probably deserving of its own question instead of an answer here, but what if we just cut out auto-dismissal entirely?

I feel like it just causes issues:

- Cases like this
- Mods who accidentally edit a post before dismissing a VLQ flag, confirming a down-vote.
- We have to understand all flags before taking any action against a post. Hypothetical, but what if a user expressed concerns in an other flag on a rude post that the OP was causing trouble in chat?
- Sometimes not all flags are helpful, especially on very bad posts that get publicity before mods address them. It would be nice to have more control post-deletion to write users comments or mark individual flags as helpful/not-helpful.

If I take the time to actually go to a post's page to read and delete/close it, it's unlikely I'll be bothered by the extra click or two to dismiss flags after taking that action.

The one exception would be when a mod casts a deleting flag, we could auto-dismiss flags of the same type. For instance, if a post has two spam flags, I'll add a third to delete it, and it doesn't make sense to keep those two original flags around, and same for VLQ.

I think that would be a lower-overhead implementation that would actually solve some other problems as well.

Comment: Well, personally, 95% of the time I like auto-dismissal. And in the one case I frequently run into where the flag is not auto-dismissed (migrating comments to chat on a "More than 20 comments..." flag), I often wish it would be. Removing auto-dismissal would add some nontrivial amount to my flag handling time, so I'm not in favor.